# Flutter build appbundle giving error when using stripe

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am trying to build an appbundle for my flutter application. I was able to build it perfectly before, but now when I added
`stripe_payment: ^1.0.11`
I am getting this error:

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithR8ForRelease'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:releaseRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve net.minidev:json-smart: 2.3.0.                   
     Required by:                                                       
         project :app                                                   
      > Skipped due to earlier error                                    
   > Could not resolve net.minidev:json-smart:[1.3.1,2.3].              
     Required by:                                                       
         project :app > com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:7.8                
      > Failed to list versions for net.minidev:json-smart.             
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/net/minidev/json-smart/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/net/minidev/json-smart/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/net/minidev/json-smart/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: This issue is from ReactNative, but I think it stems from the same cause, so you may find a solution here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/32734

Comment: Tried those steps but none of them worked